# Using Ninject as my IDependencyResolver has serious issues? Please assist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, razor, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I created an NinjectResolver which implements IDependencyResolver.  In the global.asax, I'm setting this guy as my DependencyResolver.

However, in doing so, I lose all of my data-dash attributes on validaiton.  And it also messes up the entire client-side paging, sorting on my grid (using Telerik's MVC extensions).

Here's the class:

```
public class NinjectResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public IKernel Kernel
    {
        get
        {
            return _kernel;
        }
    }

    public NinjectResolver(params Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[] modules)
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    public IBindingToSyntax<T> Bind<T>()
    {
        return _kernel.Bind<T>();
    }
}
```

And here's my app start in global.asax ...

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        .... omitted

        var modules = new Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[] 
        { 
            new PersistenceModule()
        };

        var dependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(modules);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(dependencyResolver);

        .... omitted
    }
```

If I comment out the SetResolver line, all my client-side validation works as well as my client-side grid sorting, paging, filtering, etc.  Unfortunately, I lose all my constructor injection.

Any help is appreciated please.  Not sure if I have to add more modules for client side operations to work?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 instead of writing your own implementation? It is widely used and proven to work in many projects.

Comment: Sweet.  That did the trick.  For some reason, I thought validation providers, etc., was already right out of Ninject by default.  Much appreciated and the code is very clean.  Thanks!